# Modal using Bootstrap and Ajax Doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having trouble loading the modal using the jQuery ajax when it call the jQuery function is shows that dialogs but it doesn't show any Modal which is called by the jQuery.
I don't know where I made the mistake. Is there anybody who can help me to fix out this bug?

**View File**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery call**

```
$(function(){
   $('.gift').click(function(){
      var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
      //alert("asdfasdf");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

The place from where I called the ajax:

```
<i id="<?php echo $row->id?>" class="fa fa-gift fa-lg text-danger ico gift" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send Gifts to your near ones"> 49</i>
```

Comment: Works for me, have you tried checking your console for errors?
http://jsfiddle.net/h8pkha0a/

Comment: The actual problem was that mistakely used two jquery plugins of different version. Anyway its working now :) thank you @DanielSanchez for your effort